# Finding the equation of a line with the given information (see picture)

Tags: geometry

[image]

The equation to the line is x/b + y/a = 1

What i want to know is how do you get there? i tried using point slope formula and got nothing but wrong answers. Can anyone point out how to get the equation above?

Comment: Please read the tags before applying them to your post - the algebraic-geometry tag specifically says "[t]his tag should not be used for elementary questions involving both algebra and geometry."

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Use the two-point form of a line $$\dfrac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\dfrac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}$$ You are given $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$.

Comment: x/b - y/a = 0??

Comment: $\dfrac{x-0}{b-0}=\dfrac{y-a}{0-a}$.